# Let $A \in O_n$, such that it's characteristic polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors with real roots. What can I say about $A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of a matrix $A \in O_n$ that  $\vert \lambda \vert = 1$. The characteristic polynomial has only roots in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $\lambda = \pm1$. The Eigenraum spanned by $\lambda = 1$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $0^n$ for $\lambda = -1$ .

Hence I can conclude that $A^2$ = $A$ and $A = Id$, because $AAv = A \lambda v = Av = \lambda v = v$?

Can I assume that the absolute value of $\lambda$ is 1 over the complex vector space and transfer it to the real vector space? I assume no and my proof is wrong, because orthonormal matrices could obviously have other real valued eigenvalues, but why exactly? What else could I say about $A^2$?

Comment: Well, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. This means that $A^2$ is similar to the identity matrix, i.e. $A^2$ is the identity matrix. You don't need the complex field here.